# ORA-28500: [ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]: Attempt to access a column "UtilizaMetrica_DescontoComerci" {42S22,NativeErr = 207} - Column +30 character

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, heterogeneous-services

I configure a Heterogenous Service from Oracle to access SQL Server using the ODBC Drive from Microsoft

It works, but some query in specific table return the right message for example:

> ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Attempt to access a column 'UtilizaMetrica_DescontoComerci'. {42S22,NativeErr = 207}[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]

The right column `'UtilizaMetrica_DescontoComercial'` has 32 characters, but truncate in the return message to 30 characters

Comment: @OldProgrammer i don't understand your point, this link is not even relate to my problem.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using ?

Comment: @GMB `SELECT @@VERSION` = `Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4293802) - 13.0.5081.1 (X64)`

Comment: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/5753

Comment: The name of the column,`UtilizaMetrica_DescontoComerci`, is 30 characters long.

Comment: The right name is `UtilizaMetrica_DescontoComercial` the error not show the last `al`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [OHS has a limitation](https://community.oracle.com/thread/697029) on the length of a column name (30 characters).

Workaround is to shorten the name to an acceptable length by defining a shorter alias for that column or using a view to do the same thing.

Comment: `UtilizaMetrica_DescontoComerci` is 30 characters long.

Comment: @BobJarvis OP has already written that the column name is 31 characters. Shall we guess that the error message has already truncated the name because - you know - it doesn't support names that are longer?

Comment: I'm just calling out the inconsistency. I'd expect OP to post a clarification. I will point out that in Portugese the phrase "Utiliza métrica desconto comercial" means "Uses commercial discount metrics" (per Google Translate), so the question is "Did the message drop two characters, or only one?".

Comment: Your right @Bob Jarvis, I was thinking if there anything else that could be done or has to be as SMor said, rename the column or use a view

Comment: The right name is `UtilizaMetrica_DescontoComercial` the error not show the last two `al`

Comment: @BobJarvis Then call out the inconsistency as a comment to OP's question and make that exact point. What you did post was not helpful, sounds a little sarcastic, and is more than a little pedantic. And obviously wrong as we see now.